# Extracting certain strings from a substring using Python

Tags: python, string, search, split

I have a large document which I am trying to extract certain data from using Pythonv3. Text similar to the below is repeated and I want to extract the "123456789" and "987654321" each time the "pic=" and "originalName=" strings are identified.

> "this is some text pic=123456789 some more text originalName="987654321.jpg then some more text"

Can anyone assist?

Comment: Sounds like you want regular expressions. https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to use python's library for [regular expressions](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html). Regular expressions are a useful way to search for patterns in text. In this case, the other commenters have already provided a working snippet:

```
import re
s= 'this is some text pic=123456789 some more text originalName="987654321.jpg then some more text'
data = re.findall('(?<=pic\=)\d+|(?<=originalName\=\")\d+', s)
```

This looks like nonsense at first, so here's a breakdown:

[re.findall](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.findall) returns all matches to the specified pattern in the specified string.

The first parameter to findall is the regular expression pattern, enclosed by single quotes. A regular expression can be just a word; `re.findall('apple', s)` would return all instances of the word "apple" in s. However, there are several characters with special [meaning](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax) to help describe more general patterns.

`\d` matches any digit 0-9. `\d+` matches a sequence of digits 0-9 of any length.

The `|` in the middle separates two regular expressions. If either pattern is matched, the overall expression returns a match.

`(?<= ... )` is called a positive lookbehind. This returns a match if there's a pattern that is *preceded* by the pattern described in the `...`.

`=` and `"` have special meanings, so `\=` and `\"` specify that those characters are supposed to be used normally.

So `'(?<=pic\=)\d+'` matches a sequence of digits of any length that is preceded by the string `pic=`. And `'(?<=originalName\=\")\d+'`matches a sequence of digits preceded by the string `originalName="`.

The second parameter to findall is just the string to search for these patterns. So `re.findall('(?<=pic\=)\d+|(?<=originalName\=\")\d+', s)` will search s and return all sequences of digits with `pic=` before them, and all sequences of digits with `originalName="` before them.

Comment: Thank you! Makes perfect sense. How do I add characters in there too? I just realised some of my originalNames also have letters. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
import re
s= 'this is some text pic=123456789 some more text originalName="987654321.jpg then some more text'
data = re.findall('(?<=pic\=)\d+|(?<=originalName\=\")\d+', s)
```

Output:

```
['123456789', '987654321']
```

Comment: `data = re.findall('(?<=pic\=)\d+|(?<=originalName\=\")\d+', s)`

Comment: I'd recommend you start putting more effort into your answers than "try this"... Do you not want OP to understand what they are running? They clearly have no experience with regex.